# Access properties from application controller in a rendered template

Tags: layout, ember.js, properties, controller, ember-cli

I have these properties set on my application controller

```
monthToParse: null,
yearToParse: null,

fullDateToParse: function() {
    // set array to month names
    var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
    // set a variable to a new date object
    var date = new Date();
    // set the month to the previous month and return that
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
    // set the controller properties for use in other parts of the app
    this.set('monthToParse', monthNames[date.getMonth()]);
    this.set('yearToParse', date.getFullYear());

    return this.get('monthToParse') + ' ' + this.get('yearToParse');
}.property('monthToParse', 'yearToParse'),
```

And they work in my application.hbs.

But I also need to access them in my rendered views layout file.

In index.hbs I'm rendering a bunch of pages like this...

```
{{render "page-01"}}
{{render "page-02"}}
{{render "page-03"}}
...
```

and each has a view file that tells it to use a pages layout file like this

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
    layoutName: 'page'
});
```

But in each page.hbs file when I try to reference the applications properties using this technique

## In the page controller file

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: 'application'
});
```

## In the page.hbs handlebars file

```
<p>{{controllers.application.fullDateToParse}}</p>
```

My first thought is that maybe the page.hbs layout file that these pages are using is not properly connected to the controller? Or maybe the nested layout and the way I'm rendering it is off.

Comment: I would probably create a [mixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html) and extend the controllers that need that method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe by calling `{{render 'page-01'}}`, you're telling Ember to render the `page-01` template with a `page-01` controller. You could use the [Ember inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) to find out.

You might be able to fix this somehow, but a better solution would be to make your pages into [components](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/), and pass in their dependencies explicitly:

```
{{x-page fullDate=fullDateToParse}}
```

Then, in your `x-page` components template, you can just use

```
{{fullDate}}
```

---

Note, depending on what `page` actually is in your app, there may be a better name for the component than x-page

Comment: So what if I have 7 pages and each page has a totally different layout, do I need to make a component for each of those pages? Can I use something other than render to help this problem as well?

Comment: If you're already using a different layout for each page (different .hbs files, right?), why not use components instead?

Comment: In Ember 2.0, you basically won't be writing controllers or views anymore.